# How to read XML in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML file which looks like this

```
<ss:demo>
<ss:Name>
    <ss:FirstName>First</ss:FirstName>
    <ss:SecondName>Second</ss:SecondName>
</ss:Name>
<ss:country code="IN">India</ss:country>
</ss:demo>
```

How can I read this using C#.
Please help me in this. which will be easiest way for reading it? I tried to read it into a DataSet but its showing some error.

Comment: What error is it showing, and what do you want to do with the XML after you have read it in?

Comment: What code did you use to read it?

Comment: I can see two XML errors: no namespace declaration and `IN` isn't in quotes in the `code` attribute. My answer expects the second to be fixed and works regardless of the first.

Comment: I have only written the inner code. everything is there in it. And also "" is also there. When i wrote here i wrote the mistake.

Answer (score 6):

There are several strategies to read an XML document, or parts thereof, using C#.  If you are more specific about what you want to do with the XML document, the community can provide you with more specific guidance.

Here are some top choices:

Linq to XML

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387065.aspx

XDocument (part of the Linq to XML framework)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx

XmlDocument

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

XPath

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx

Answer (score 3):

How about just [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)?

Given this:

```
var xml = "<ss:demo>\r\n<ss:Name>\r\n    <ss:FirstName>First</ss:FirstName>\r\n    <ss:SecondName>" +
"Second</ss:SecondName>\r\n</ss:Name>\r\n<ss:country code=\"IN\">India</ss:country>\r\n</ss" +
":demo>";
```

(Note I had to wrap `IN` in quotes as such `"IN"`)

Declare some namespaces and read it in:

```
var mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager( new NameTable() );
mngr.AddNamespace( "ss", "urn:ignore" ); // or proper URL
var parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, mngr, null, XmlSpace.None, null);
```

If reading from a string as above:

```
var txtReader = new XmlTextReader( xml, XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext );
```

If reading from a file instead:

```
var txtReader = new XmlTextReader( new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open), XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext );
```

Then load:

```
var ele = XElement.Load( txtReader );
```

`ele` contains everything you need.

Comment: You meant **XDocument.Load** in this case, right?  (downvote was not from me)

Comment: Yes it's a file, but to show an example I used a string. I've updated to include what it would be like with a file.