# How to parse HTML or convert HTML to XML so I extract the information out of the website (in C#)

Tags: c#, html, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Is there a way to parse HTML or convert HTML to XML so I extract the information out of the website easily?

I'm working with C#.

Thank you,

Comment: You should check out the [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) is what you are looking for. Check out this tutorial [Parsing HTML Document with HTMLAgilityPack](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the COM objects in `Microsoft HTML Object Library` to load HTML, and then use it's object model to navigate around. An example is shown below:

```
string html;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(new Uri("http://www.google.com")))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
  html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)new HTMLDocument();
doc.write(html);
foreach (IHTMLElement el in doc.all)
  Console.WriteLine(el.tagName);
```